# gdi+ PrivateFontCollection AddFontFile always returns status with "InvalidParameter"

Tags: c++, fonts, gdi+, win32gui, typeface

every one, I'm using GDI+ to rendering text with my own typeface, but I always get a error status `InvalidParameter` when using member function **AddFontFile(WCHAR*)** of **PrivateFontCollection** to load my font file, here is my code:

```
PrivateFontCollection m_font_collection;
... // initialize window
GdiplusStartup(&gdi_token, &gdi_startup_input, NULL);
// here the result always is 2 (that specified as "InvalidParameter")
Status result = m_font_collection.AddFontFile(L"myfont.ttf");
```

I can't find any explanation why this error occur, does anyone knows how to fix that problem? Thanks!
ps: forgive my poor English... :)

---

I've solved this problem, this is a stupid question, so, forgive me... please check my answer below
[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30034530/4431254)

Comment: obvious question: is your own typeface broken? (i.e can you install it on Windows, does TTX signal any problems with it, will fontforge load it, etc)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for your comment, I've solved this problem, please check my answer~ :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I've solved this problem... how stupid I am... the question is quite stupid, I defined the **m_font_collection** too early! It should be defined after the function **GdiplusStartup** has been called, only after the GDI+ has been initialized the **PrivateFontCollection** can load your own font files... Hope can help somebody

Comment: It would be better to GDI+ gave an error saying it wasn't initialized